# print value of one column the number of times specified in another column

Tags: perl, unix

I have data that I want to reformat in unix, taking columns 2-3 to make a new column (called when in the example), but am having trouble figuring out how to do this. Without changing columns 4-7, which together serve as the identifier for the data, I want to print column 2 the number of times specified in column 3, then print a value (31 in this example) N (= column 1 for each identifier) minus (the sum of column 3 for each identifier) number of times. So the reformatted data will have a total of N number of lines for each identifier.
The data to start with looks like this:

```
N   time    awake   line    sex temp    rep
9   15  1   188 f   25  1
9   20  1   188 f   25  1
9   21  1   188 f   25  1
9   28  1   188 f   25  1
10  12  1   205 m   25  1   
10  14  3   205 m   25  1   
10  16  1   205 m   25  1   
10  18  1   205 m   25  1   
10  19  2   205 m   25  1   
10  22  1   205 m   25  1   
10  24  1   205 m   25  1
```

The reformatted data should hopefully look something like this:

```
line    sex temp    rep when
188 f   25  1   15
188 f   25  1   20
188 f   25  1   21
188 f   25  1   28
188 f   25  1   31
188 f   25  1   31
188 f   25  1   31
188 f   25  1   31
188 f   25  1   31
205 m   25  1   12
205 m   25  1   14
205 m   25  1   14
205 m   25  1   14
205 m   25  1   16
205 m   25  1   18
205 m   25  1   19
205 m   25  1   19
205 m   25  1   22
205 m   25  1   24
```

My guess is that it requires some sort of loop, I think the pseudocode would look something like this:

```
for (each columns 4-7)
    tot = (column 1)
    rem = tot - sum (column 3)
    for (i=0; i <= column 3; i++)
        print column 2"\n"
    for (j=0; i <= rem; j++)
        print "31\n"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Edited to add:
I've tried modifying the perl code from @mvp below but it's not quite right. I used awk to reformat the original columns 4-7 into a single field (and variable) called id. Any comments?

```
print "id       when\n"; # output header
my $temp='188.f.25.1';
my $count;
my $rest;
my $total;
while(my $input = <>) {
    my ($n, $time, $awake, $id)
        = split /\s+/, $input; # read each line
    next if $n eq 'N'; # skip input header line
    if ($id eq $temp) {
        $count++;
        for (1..$awake) {print "$id     $time\n";}
        $total = $n;
        next;
    }
    else {
        $rest=$total-$count;
        for (1..$rest) {print "$temp    31\n";}
    }
    $count=0;
    $temp = $id;
    next;
}
```

And the modified input file:

```
N       time    awake   line.sex.temp.rep
9       15      1       188.f.25.1
9       20      1       188.f.25.1
9       21      1       188.f.25.1
9       28      1       188.f.25.1
10      12      1       205.m.25.1
10      14      3       205.m.25.1
10      16      1       205.m.25.1
10      18      1       205.m.25.1
10      19      2       205.m.25.1
10      22      1       205.m.25.1
10      24      1       205.m.25.1
10      10      1       206.m.25.1
10      14      1       206.m.25.1
10      18      1       206.m.25.1
10      20      1       206.m.25.1
10      24      1       206.m.25.1
10      26      1       206.m.25.1
10      27      1       206.m.25.1
10      28      2       206.m.25.1
```

Comment: So with the new data format, what's your desired output?

Comment: @Kenosis The desired output is actually the same, except at least initially the first four columns of the original desired output would be a single field separated by periods, that I would've re-separated using awk (due to my being a newbie, couldn't really figure out how to do this all at once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using `awk`. It uses the unmodified input file. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file{,} | column -t
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    print "line sex temp rep when"
}

FNR==NR && NR>1 {
    a[$4,$5,$6,$7]+=$3
    next
}

FNR>1 {
    for (i=1;i<=$3;i++) {
        print x=($4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7), $2
        a[$4,$5,$6,$7]--
        var++
    }

    if (a[$4,$5,$6,$7]==0) { 
        for (i=1;i<=$1-var;i++) {
            print x, "31"
        }
        var=0
    }
}
```

Results:

```
line  sex  temp  rep  when
188   f    25    1    15
188   f    25    1    20
188   f    25    1    21
188   f    25    1    28
188   f    25    1    31
188   f    25    1    31
188   f    25    1    31
188   f    25    1    31
188   f    25    1    31
205   m    25    1    12
205   m    25    1    14
205   m    25    1    14
205   m    25    1    14
205   m    25    1    16
205   m    25    1    18
205   m    25    1    19
205   m    25    1    19
205   m    25    1    22
205   m    25    1    24
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "line sex temp rep when" } FNR==NR && NR>1 { a[$4,$5,$6,$7]+=$3; next } FNR>1 { for (i=1;i<=$3;i++) { print x=($4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7), $2; a[$4,$5,$6,$7]--; var++ } if (a[$4,$5,$6,$7]==0) { for (i=1;i<=$1-var;i++) print x, "31"; var=0 } }' file{,} | column -t
```

Comment: would you mind commenting on what this does?: a[$4,$5,$6,$7]--

Comment: @suegene: Not a problem; `a[$4,$5,$6,$7]--` simply decrements (by one) the multidimensional array holding columns 4,5,6 and 7.

Comment: Thanks, I think I finally got it, didn't realize how the array was structured until just now. very nice!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in Perl:

Save this as `myscript.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "line    sex temp    rep when\n"; # output header
while(my $input = <>) {
    my ($n, $time, $awake, $line, $sex, $temp, $rep)
        = split /\s+/, $input;
    next if $n eq 'N'; # skip input header line
    for (1..$awake) {
        print "$line $sex  $temp $rep $time\n";
    }
}
```

Call it as `myscript.pl <a.txt >b.txt`

Comment: Would you mind expanding your answer to include how to read in the data file (we can call is a.txt) and output to the reformatted file (b.txt)?

Comment: Added usage, please see my amended answer

Comment: I've run the script and it looks like a partial solution so far. It doesn't address printing the lines to have the value "31" filled in the last column of the reformatted file. This is the output I'm getting (sorry, don't know how to get this to show up properly):205 m  25 1 14
205 m  25 1 16
205 m  25 1 18
205 m  25 1 19
205 m  25 1 19
205 m  25 1 22
205 m  25 1 24
206 m  25 1 10
206 m  25 1 14
206 m  25 1 18
206 m  25 1 20
206 m  25 1 24
206 m  25 1 26
206 m  25 1 27
206 m  25 1 28
206 m  25 1 28

Comment: I see, I completely missed that part. I can try to add this for you, or you can do it yourself - your pseudo-code has it already :-)

Comment: ah, I'd definitely appreciate it if you'd add it, I'll try in the meanwhile to do it myself but I'm guessing my unfamiliarity with perl syntax is going to hamper me quite a bit. Specifically, I'm not sure at all how you'd get the sum of column 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F -lane 'if($.==1){print "@F[3,4,5,6,1]"}for($i=0;$i<$F[2];$i++){print "@F[3,4,5,6,1]"}' your_file
```

or you could also use this:

```
perl -F -lane 'for($i=0;($i<$F[2])||($.==1);$i++){print "@F[3,4,5,6,1]";if($.==1){last}}' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> cat temp
N       time    awake   line    sex     temp    rep
9       15      1       188     f       25      1
9       20      1       188     f       25      1
9       21      1       188     f       25      1
9       28      1       188     f       25      1
10      12      1       205     m       25      1
10      14      3       205     m       25      1
10      16      1       205     m       25      1
10      18      1       205     m       25      1
10      19      2       205     m       25      1
10      22      1       205     m       25      1
10      24      1       205     m       25      1
```

Execution:

```
> perl -F -lane 'if($.==1){print "@F[3,4,5,6,1]"}for($i=0;$i<$F[2];$i++){print "@F[3,4,5,6,1]"}' temp
line sex temp rep time
188 f 25 1 15
188 f 25 1 20
188 f 25 1 21
188 f 25 1 28
205 m 25 1 12
205 m 25 1 14
205 m 25 1 14
205 m 25 1 14
205 m 25 1 16
205 m 25 1 18
205 m 25 1 19
205 m 25 1 19
205 m 25 1 22
205 m 25 1 24
>
```